# VBA Evaluate a string as function in certain scope

Tags: excel, vba

everyone. I got a kind of problem. I wrote a function which takes a string as an argument, representing a function name and an Arguments Array with the parameters. I store the function name followed all the parameters between parentheses and separated by commas. Then Call the Evaluate function and pass this variable to it. It works ok when I pass a function name defined in Global Scope, but I want to be able to call a private function defined inside a class I wrote. Any suggestions?

```js
Private Function fAsString(fname As String, ParamArray arguments() As Variant)
    
    tx = fname & "("
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(arguments)
        it = arguments(i)
        
        If TypeName(it) = "String" Then
            it = """" & LCase(it) & """"
        ElseIf TypeName(it) = "Date" Then
            it = "DateValue(""" & Month(it) & " " & Day(it) & ", " & Year(it) & """)"
        End If
        
        tx = tx & it & IIf(i = UBound(arguments), _
            ")", _
            ", ")
    Next
    
    fAsString = Evaluate(tx)
End Function
```

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a good question for SO.  There's a code review site within stack change that you might look into if you're looking for general feedback on your code.

Comment: @ebrts I think it fits, it's just not that well worded. He's not looking for feedback, but rather direction on how scoping works when calling `Evaluate`. Unfortunately I've no idea.